# How to integrate facebook signup/register on regular login website?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem of thinking of how to integrate 3rd party login (also do silent register) on website where already is used regular login/register system.

Basically current login is quite regular:

1. As user enters website session
   class determines if he need to
   re-login.
2. When user login all kind of sessions and cookies are set and
   user get access to restricted areas.

Users table in mysql has quite a lot fields also password fields.

What i wondering is how you create user entry in the same database table if it's not there and do full (silent) register for that facebook user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i'm not sure what you mean by *silent register*, but you can *simplify* your regular signup process if the user is connected to Facebook.

This is what we do:

1. When a user comes to our website (unauthenticated - no cookie set in browser), we check to see if this user is connected to Facebook
2. If the user is connected to Facebook and has connected before, we "sign them in" to our website
3. If the user is connected to Facebook and has **not** connected before, we do a call to the Facebook Graph API to grab some user details (name, email, etc), redirect the user to our signup page and fill in most of the details using the Facebook info we just received.

We have a seperate database table for Facebook users - we store the Facebook Unique ID and the user's email address.

The email address is very important - this is what we use to perform a single sign on, as the user's Facebook email address should match the email address for the website.

Comment: By silent i ment like your solution just without redirecting them to register form form normal signups. Get all data needed and enter them in database. So the user feels like hes actually just login in with facebook.

Comment: Also facebook documentation is little bit confusing for me since i never have used it before.

Answer (score 0):

**OpenID is a safe, faster, and easier way to log in to web sites.**
:D
use open id ...

there is many lib in this address http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries

each user can login with user in facebook and gmail and you must give each user id and relation models for access

Comment: Thanks for link openid is very good approach for doing this, but in my case another 3rd party website besides facebook i need to login users with is not using openid :(

Comment: Users will show you middle finger if you ask them to make openID instead of Facebook. That is what they will do.

Answer (score -1):

I am also new to this but got some idea how to do and i would like to share it.

You can use the Javascript API provided by Facebook, Google+ etc to make login into the site. The API has in-built methods which invoked for authentication and pulling data from the user's account(which is customizable what user data to pull). In between the javascript code you can write ajax call to your server script with user data(got from the third party server) for making the user signup or login into your system, what ever want to do.

Yes the configuration of all these are bit headache :-(